# Fetch all data from mysql database using prepared call or query string

Tags: mysql

I need to show all data from database in a single page when button is clicked.
I have used the query

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from emp where empno=$num");
```

I have created an **html** page in which when you enter employee number it will fetch data from database and show the result. 
In the same way instead of a single record in need to display all records in the same page.

Any idea which query to use?

Comment: Here is my php code <?php
$num=$_POST['empno'];
include("conn.php");
$res=mysql_query("select * from emp where empno=$num");
while($r=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
echo $r[0]."--".$r[1]."--".$r[2]."--".$r[3]."--".$r[4]."--".$r[5]."<br>";
}
?>

Comment: That should be edited into the question, it's too important to miss out.

Comment: emp is the name of the table i which data is inserted.

Comment: I mean can't you just use the query `SELECT * FROM emp`.

Comment: @jim I have used select* from emp code which is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to correctly understand your question... but to get all results you need to use `select * from emp`. By this, you should get all entrys from the table `emp`.

After this, you have to go trough the result set with your while loop and echo out row by row.

At the end, a little hint... why do you not use **mysqli_...** because it is the improved version and prevents sql injections.

Try the following to get the sql result as table:

```
<?php

$num = $_POST['empno'];
include("conn.php");

$res = mysql_query("select * from emp");

echo '<table>';
while($r = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$r[0].'</td><td>'.$r[1].'</td><td>'.$r[2].'</td><td>'.$r[3].'</td><td>'.$r[4].'</td><td>'.$r[5].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';

?>
```

I have not tested it, but it should work.

Comment: I have figured out the answer. Select * from emp is the code which i have used.

Comment: by the way, if you have to sort the result you can use `SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY yoursortcolumn ASC` to sort A-Z or `SELECT * FROM emp ORDER BY yoursortcolumn DESC` to sort Z-A.

Comment: how do i show data from database using td, tr tag? I need the result to be displayed in table format

Comment: I have edited my above answer, please take a look on it. Hope it works.